# indentation with a single dollar sign

Tags: debugging, emacs, indentation

This is an Emacs config question.

I've got code indentation trouble using Emacs-26.1 with markdown-mode version 2.4-dev in Ubuntu 19.04. I also have Polymode and Auctex installed. I am pretty sure that Emacs is trying to use tex mode when it should use markdown mode, but it is not always doing that.

Sometimes I get a giant indent. I am writing in an "*.md" file, intending to write markdown. As I write about shell programs, I sometimes have one dollar sign in code examples. I'm pasting a literal example.  I've tried to insert a commented-out dollar sign to prevent this, but Emacs indents that enoromously.

````
```shell
az vm create --resource-group $grpName --name pj80 \
      --image UbuntuLTS --custom-data cloud-init-tc.txt \
      --generate-ssh-keys
```

                               <!-- $ -->
````

The automatic indentation tries moves all text under the variable "grpname".  It does that until I insert another dollar sign. I *guess* this is happening because Polymode wants to interpret the dollar sign as a math inline.

When text should be flush left, I often get a 4 space indent if I accidentally hit TAB.

There are too many moving parts in this, I don't know which I should be trying to fix. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I would check:

1. <kbd>C-h m</kbd> to verify the buffer is using the correct modes you expect.
2. Check what `indent-line-function` and `indent-region-function` are set to use.  Consider browsing the source for these functions and see if there are any obvious configuration points for your mode.

Comment: It was using TeX mode, not markdown mode. Going to have to read polymode docs to fix.